# When does a website require multiple HTML files?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Are all the HTML files linked to the same JavaScript file, or do you need multiple JavaScript files? Is there ever a point where you need multiple CSS files?

Comment: When you visit a website you are loading the html delivered to the page that you see.
its actually the otherway arround where html files link javascript pages?
html pages also have their stylesheets linked to them?

are you trying to make a site? with more context about what youre curious about or trying to do can help illuminate more information.

Comment: If you are using VanillaJS and jQuery, I recommend you to make a specific .js and .css file for each pages you have. In this case, your page will be lighter than when you have one .js and one .css.

Comment: For example, I want to make a website that features a nav bar and a side bar, with multiple links to redirect to various aspects of that website on each bar. How would the file formatting look in that case?

Answer (score 2):

When it grows large enough :)

Simple websites might only need one HTML file and no separate JS or CSS files. If a site has multiple pages that are returned from the web server, they would need to be separate HTML files (or separate rendered templates, etc.).

If a website or web app has enough JS and/or CSS that it's inconvenient to keep in one file, either because of the load time or the annoyance of editing a file that large, or the complexity of knowing which parts of the file go with which pages or components or templates, that's a good time to split those files in to multiples.

Most modern rich web applications aren't edited/written in terms of the specific files that get served to the browser anymore, instead those end-result files are produced by a bundler like Webpack, FuseBox, etc., into either single or multiple JS (and possibly CSS) files which are dynamically loaded by other internal JS code when they need to be. Smaller and simpler/less interactive websites might have multiple HTML files (or rendered templates) that share the same JS and CSS.